# Protecting backticks in substitution

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a custom mysql backup script, and part of this script should execute such statement (intention to remove .gz):

```
mysql -uroot -pmypass -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `basename -s .gz test-db.gz`"
```

but it doesn't work and produces an error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-db' at line 1
```

I know that problem is with the hyphen "-" which separates test and db.

And this statement works

```
mysql -uroot -pmypass -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`test-db.gz\`"
```

Well, how to get above statement working including command substitution which i need ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason behind that is that mysql won't allow you to create databases with a name that include hyphens. The workaround to that is to enclose the DB name with backticks which have special meaning in MYSQL to escape the reserved words.

Backticks have yet another meaning in the shell which serves for command substitution, hence in this case we need to resort to using the $() notation for the command or nested backticks, personally I prefer the former as it is more readable and also due to the fact that backticks are being deprecated in 2013 in favour of the $() syntax.

I managed to reproduce the issue that you were facing and the following commands works fine for me. Here we are escaping the backticks so that the shell won't interpret them for command substitution while mysql would still use them as an indicator to escape the "-" in "test-db"

```
mysql -uroot -p -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`$(basename -s .gz test-db.gz)\`"
```

or

```
mysql -uroot -p -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \``basename -s .gz test-db.gz`\`"
```

However if later you needed to drop that database or perform any database-level operation on it, then you need to enclose the DB name with backticks, e.g.

```
drop database `test-db`;
```

Here is a [link](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=461) to a bug in mysql in regard to having hyphens in the DB name

Comment: Did I get it right that you can enclose the database name with single quotes as well? Cannot test it myself right now

Comment: Yes, thats right, except its backticks `` not single quotes ''. Tried it myself and it did work. The purpose is to escape any reserved words in the name, the "-" in this case. For the drop statement, if you omit the backticks it will give you the same error you had initially.

Comment: If it did work for you, can you please accept the answer to make it obvious for people facing the same issue as you.

Comment: Works as expected, either first or second way good. Big Thanks Hass!